# How do I get Powershell to run a command to a bat file prompt?

Tags: powershell

I am using Powershell to run a bat file, which this bat file will open a separate command prompt.  Within that new command prompt, I have to give it specific file path with the file and extension to run an update.  The BAT file is calling a JAR file which loads the file.

Here is what I have:

```
  <#     Variables      #>

$RBT = "\\Testserver\D$\Test\Tool\Update_Loader.bat"

$RB = "\\Testserver\D$\Test\Tool\Funtimes.met"

<#  Process  #>

<#  Test #1 = Failed; Just a blank window

Start-Process "cmd.exe" "/c $RBT" -Verb RunAs -Wait

#>


<# Test #2 = Partial Fail; BAT file command prompt opened but waited for the file path insertion

Start-Process .\Update_Loader.bat

.\Update_Loader.bat \\Testserver\D$\Test\Tool\Funtimes.met

#>


<# Test #3 = Fail;  Just a blank window

Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList "/c D:\Test\Tool\Update_Loader.bat" -RedirectStandardOutput "D:\Test\Tool\Funtimes.met"

#>


<# Test #4 = Partial Fail; BAT file command prompt opened but did not deploy the file

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Start-Process "cmd.exe" "/k D:\Test\Tool\Update_Loader.bat" -Verb RunAs | Invoke-Expression "D:\Test\Tool\Funtimes.met"}

#>


<# Test #5 = Partial Fail; BAT file command prompt opened but did not deploy the file

Start-Process "cmd.exe"

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {"D:\Test\Tool\Update_Loader.bat" | Start-Process "D:\Test\Tool\Funtimes.met"}

#>
```

As you can see, I have just about tried everything to keep it as simple as possible.  I am afraid that I will have make this more complex than it needs to be.  I think I am just missing an argument or using the wrong command.

Comment: At the risk of sounding silly, have you verified that running `Update_Loader.bat` directly (outside of PowerShell on a regular `cmd` command prompt) actually does work and doesn't give you the same "blank windows" that might indicate something happening in the background?

Comment: The BAT file does work outside of PowerShell.  I am just trying to streamline this process for myself, less human error on entering the file path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
A simple function, that allows passing a command to PSWindows or PSCore

```
Function Start-ConsoleCommand
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]

    [Alias('scc')]

    Param  
    ( 
        [string]$ConsoleCommand,
        [switch]$PoSHCore
    )

    If ($PoSHCore)
    {Start-Process pwsh -ArgumentList "-NoExit","-Command  &{ $ConsoleCommand }" -Wait}
    Else
    {Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-NoExit","-Command  &{ $ConsoleCommand }" -Wait}
}
```

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, I will try your function as soon as I get a chance.